# Tutorial in google Assistant and Dialogflow

Tags: action, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm working on a tutorial step by step for google Assistant, using Dialogflow to detect intents.

Each step is related to an audio record, that i call by the Fullfiment method.

For each step i d'like to use command like : 
- previous (go back to the previous step)
- Next (next step)
- Pause (make a pause)
- repeat

But to be practical and conversationnal, i need that the user can say the command at any time. Is there a specific method to let the mic open during a the time i stream the audio response?
Have you some example of voice app that work like that ?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to have the microphone open arbitrarily while it is being used. However, the user is able to interrupt the Action at any time by saying "Hey Google", and then giving a follow-up command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nick. And do you know if it's possible to let the song in a low background, like when you ask for a new song on the spotify app?

Comment: You can use a [MediaResponse](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses) and then close the conversation, which will continue playing the music.